# animating a cube with javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

I am trying to animate this cube in Javascript.When I press a key it should move(or jump).However I am simply trying if my code works with the left key and it doesn’t.Any ideas?
this is my css (don’t look at the position or other details I just want to know what’s wrong with javascript)

```
.cuby { 
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    background-color: coral;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:40px;
}
```

and this is javascript(I am not  an expert in this language so if you see some redundant code or something that can be improved feel free to point it out).Probably the issus lies in the requestanimationframe but it’s just a huntch.

```
var cuby = document.querySelector(".cuby");
var rect = cuby.getBoundingClientRect();
var posx,posy,velx,vely, jumping;
for (key in rect){
    if (key=="x"){
        posx = rect[key];
    }
    if (key =="y"){
        posy = rect[key];
    }
};
cuby ={
    x: posx,
    y:posy,
    velx:0,
    vely:0,
    jumping :false
};

var controller={
    left:false,
    right: false,
    up: false,
    keyListener :function(event){
        var keystate = (event.type == "keydown")?true:false;
        switch (event.keycode){
            case 37:// left key
                controller.left = key_state;
            break;
            case 38:// up key
                controller.up = key_state;
            break;
            case 39:// right key
                controller.right = key_state;
            break;
        }
    }
};
loop = function(){
    if(controller.left==true){
        cuby.velx -= 0.5;
    }
    cuby.x += cuby.velx; 
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};


window.addEventListener("keydown", controller.keyListener);
window.addEventListener("keyup", controller.keyListener);
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are just updating cube object's x position .
you must modify position of the dom element in order to achieve animation.

try this in `loop function`

```
loop = function(){
    if(controller.left==true){
        cuby.velx -= 0.5;
    }
    cuby.x += cuby.velx; 
    document.querySelector(".cuby").style.left=cuby.x+"px";
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};
```

that must fix it ! let me know if it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your switch condition does not trigger as it is not event.keycode but **event.keyCode**.

Secondly you are not updating your element on dom, you are just changing values inside a variable which you have reassigned to store some properties.

Please take a look at my code and see if it works for you.

```
var cuby = document.querySelector(".cuby");
var rect = cuby.getBoundingClientRect();
var posx,posy,velx,vely, jumping;
for (key in rect){
    if (key=="x"){
        posx = rect[key];
    }
    if (key =="y"){
        posy = rect[key];
    }
};
var cubyprops ={
    x: posx,
    y:posy,
    velx:0,
    vely:0,
    jumping :false
};

var controller={
    left:false,
    right: false,
    up: false,
    keyListener :function(event){
      var keystate = (event.type == "keydown") ? true : false;
        switch (event.keyCode){
          case 37:// left key
            {
              controller.left = keystate;
            }
            break;
            case 38:// up key
                controller.up = keystate;
            break;
            case 39:// right key
                controller.right = keystate;
            break;
        }
    }
};
loop = function(){
    if(controller.left==true){
        cubyprops.velx += 0.5;
    }
    cubyprops.x += cubyprops.velx;
    cuby.style.left=cubyprops.x+"px";
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};


window.addEventListener("keydown", controller.keyListener);
window.addEventListener("keyup", controller.keyListener);
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```